# finding the td with 0 value

Tags: jquery

i have a table like this in my html page

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr id="classified">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="unclassified">
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

so, on the document.ready i want to check which column has 0 value, if value is o then hide that row,

i have written this code but doesnt seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function IsValidTableContent() {
    $('#mytable tr td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can locate that `td` with [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$("#mytable td:contains(0)");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UCgSL/

#### Warning:

If you have other cells that contains 0, but aren't exactly equal to 0, `:contains` will include those in the matches as well. This would mean that `100` or `1,000` could also show up since those also *contain* `0`. If you want only those whose values are `0`, and nothing else, you should consider using a filter:

```
$("#mytable td").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == 0;   
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UCgSL/1/

#### Custom Filter Selector

If using `.filter` is too verbose, you could roll your own filter selector:

```
$.expr[":"].exactly = function( e, i, m ) {
    return $(e).text() == m[3];
};

$("#mytable td:exactly(0)");​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UCgSL/2/

Comment: thanks that worked..thank u..i'll mark it as answer as soon as 9 mins are over...

Comment: Be careful with `contains`, it doesn't do what you think it does (see my solution).

Comment: yep checked it, that it much better, cause it will only pick the td which has text as 0, cause there wud be few rows which has value 101, this contains will apply for those also, i think

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you don't want to return also 10, here's a solution :

```
$("#mytable td").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this).text()!="0") $this.show();
   else $this.hide();
});
```

Comment: can i call this function on onclick of any anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2jWXU/)** i think this what you actually want

Comment: can i call this function on onclick of any anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

`val()` can't be applied in this case.
You can use `$(this).text()` but you the value returned is string so you have to parse it in int before comparing.